# How to publishing API created in WSO2 to WSO2 API Manager on Remote server

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-integration-studio

How do I upload the API I created in WSO2 Integration Studio installed on my own computer to the WSO2 API Manager on the remote server.

From the Add new server menu, I clicked the WSO2 Remote Server option under WSO2 and entered the host and server URL information, but it did not publish. When I examined WSO2's own documents, I could not find detailed resources about connecting to a remote server and publishing.

Can you help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register the service in the service catelog as below.

1. Start the WSO2 Micro Integrator pointing to API Manager.
2. You should have the carbon app of that particular service in the Micro Integrator.
3. When Micro Integrator starts it registers the available services in the API Manager.
4. From logging into the APIM publisher you can create an API.

Instructions are available here - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/integrate/develop/working-with-service-catalog/

Comment: Hi 

When I run it by doing the necessary steps on the link you have given, I get a certificate error. Because the Api Manager UI I installed on the Linux server works as https. And since I specified this information in the deployment.toml file, I think it gives the following error. How can I solve this?


`Error occurred while reading the response from service catalog javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: validity check failed`

Api Manager  3.2.0
Micro Integration Server   4.1.0
Integration Studio  8.1.0

Comment: This error is due to the missing certificates. You need to add the certificate of the API Manager in the Mico Integrator.

Comment: API Manager has not certificate. So Should I add certficate in API MAnager ?

Comment: You can't use APIM v320 with Micro Integrator 410. This service catalog feature was introduced in APIM v4.x onwards. You can comment out service_catalog section in the deployment.toml of MI.

Comment: You can use the Swagger definition you got from Integration Studio and create an API manually in the APIM publisher

Answer (score 1):

Can you add your integration studio version and WSO2 Api Manager version?
You can try this documentation https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/integrate/develop/working-with-service-catalog/

Comment: Hi 

When I run it by doing the necessary steps on the link you have given, I get a certificate error. Because the Api Manager UI I installed on the Linux server works as https. And since I specified this information in the deployment.toml file, I think it gives the following error. How can I solve this?


`Error occurred while reading the response from service catalog javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: validity check failed`

Api Manager  3.2.0
Micro Integration Server   4.1.0
Integration Studio  8.1.0

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: OK, can you try download public certificate from your WSO2 Api Manager and add this certificate to eclipse or java cacerts?